How to create a basic line chart in Power BI?
I have a simple table imported from Excel to Power BI with X and Y columns like this.
x|y
2|4
5|6
7|9

Now I want to plot those x,y coordinates ( (2,4); (5,6); (7,9) ) in a chart and draw a line that connects each of them.
But when I select a line chart and drag the Y column to the Y-axis of the Visualizations pane, it automatically sets it to be a Sum.
If I click that dropdown I can change it other calculation (min, max, count...).
But I don't want to calculate anything. Just want the raw number coordinates.
Both columns are already set to decimal data type and "Don't summarize" in the Sumarization property.
How to do that?

Create a measure and drop that in your y axis.
new y = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[y]) 

