How to combine multipe scatter charts into one in Power BI?
I want to create a chart like this one in Power BI.

I already have it in Excel and there it is a combo of three Scatter charts.
One for each line and one for the single dot.
I was able to create a scatter chart in Power BI but just with one of the three.
Need to combine all three in the same chart.
Or it could be also create just one chart as long as it is possible to add the two lines and single dot in the same one.
How to do that?
Pasting the data per request:
Line 1 Xval | Line1 YVal
10 | 2
11 | 3
12 | 4
13 | 5
14 | 6
15 | 7
Line 2 Xval | Line2 YVal
10 | 1
11 | 2
12 | 3
13 | 4
14 | 5
15 | 6
dot Xval | dot Yval
12 | 5

Can you paste your sample data as copiable text?

Follow these steps to get this:

Start tables are called Table1, Table2, Table3 and look like this.



In each table, add a custom column and call it name. The custom column should be Line 1, Line 2 or Line 3 depending on the table.


Double click the Line 1 Xval  etc columns and rename as x and y so each final table looks like this.

Click on Append Queries as New


Close and load.
Drop a line chart on the canvas.

Complete the field wells as follows dragging fields from Append1 (your new table) and then format as you please.


Thanks for the awesome detailed answer. A question there. I see the end result is "Sum of y" on the Y axis. That won't work for me. I need to plot the values without summing them up. Otherwise if there are two equal values for X, it will sum the corresponding Y values and distorce the chart. You even helped me with that on another post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78386580/how-to-create-a-basic-line-chart-in-power-bi. The problem is that solution of that post doesn't allow more than one line.

PowerBI (and dataviz in general) works by aggregating data. I'm not sure I understand the issue though so it might be an idea to mark this as solved and ask another question with the exact issue and  your desired result.

Sure. Thanks @davidebacci. Basically just add a duplicate coordinate in the dataset and run it again and you will see what I mean. Anyway I posted the new question as requested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78404568/how-to-plot-duplicate-values-on-a-multiple-lines-chart-without-summing-them-up
