How to plot duplicate values on a multiple lines chart without summing them up?
Creating this question per request from @davidebacci here:
How to combine multipe scatter charts into one in Power BI?
I want to create a chart exactly like the one I posted on the above question.
But I need it to allow values to repeat.
So the dataset for that chart would be this new one:
Line 1 Xval | Line1 YVal
10 | 2
11 | 3
12 | 4
13 | 5
14 | 6
15 | 7
15 | 10 (new value)
Line 2 Xval | Line2 YVal
10 | 1
11 | 2
12 | 3
13 | 4
14 | 5
15 | 6
15 | 6 (new value)
dot Xval | dot Yval
12 | 5
I just added two new coordinates (15, 10) for Line 1 (which duplicates the number 15 on Xval) and another (15, 6) coordinate for Line 2 (duplicating that exact same coordinate that already existed).
The solution on that post doesn't allow duplicate values as it interprets Xval as an Id for relationship, while in reality they should be just (x, y) coordinates that can repeat themselves sometimes.
And if the same coordinate repeats, it should just plot that same coordinate again in the same place instead of suming them up with the other duplicate value.
For instance, the two (15, 6) coordinates on Line 2 should result in one (15, 6) ploted on the chart, not (15, 12) which would be the sum of the y value of each of them.
So, the resulting chart for these values should be like this (as I have in excel):


I think the line 2 (15,6) is fine as you can write a measure that just plots the max (i.e. it will select one of the duplicates).
What do you want to happen for the line 1 (15,10). Do you want 15,10 and 15,7 to both be plotted? How would a line connect these? You need some kind of aggregation to plot on a line chart in PowerBI.

myY = MAX(Append1[y]) 

To plot individual points, you can switch to a scatter chart but then you can't have your lines.


Yes, for line 1 I want to plot both (15, 7) and (15, 10) like in the scatter chart of your answer. In fact if you see my last question, it was about scatter instead of line chart. Then I do need a line that connects the dots. In some cases, like that one, it will not be a straight line. Sometimes it can become a curve. Isn't really possible to do that on Power BI? I have that on Excel. There it is a Combo chart (three scatter charts, one for each data set). Nothing similar on Power BI to achive the same result? And Excel allows creating the line and dashed line on scatter charts.

I added to the original question the chart generated by excel for the sample data of this question.

I understand. Unfortunately, this is a limitation of the current PowerBI line chart - you have to aggregate somehow. You would need to use Deneb to do what you want

ok. That's kind of unbelievable though. This is the first chart I try to create on Power BI and came to it on the idea it was Excel on steroids for charts creation. When in fact it's behind on this one.

in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78386580/how-to-create-a-basic-line-chart-in-power-bi you taught me to create a measure on line chart. That doesn't require sum. So would work. The only issue I found there is that I could place just one line on the chart. Would't it be possible to have more than one line using measures? If yes, it should solve the issue.

Yes, you can place multiple measures on there. To place more than one measure, remove the legend field from the field well

You mean remove the content from Legend field of Visualizations pane? That legend field is already blank. I placed two values in X-axis: Xval and Xval2. In the Y-axis I placed newY (measure). Now, when I try to add newY2 on Y-axis it doesn't allow.

Hard to know what you're doing. From what you're saying, I don't think it will work though. It is just a current limitation of the line chart.

I could evolve on this. Was able to create the two lines without sum. To do that I used measure as you proposed before. For line 2 it works out perfectly. But for line 1 it is not plottting (15, 7) and (15, 10). I created a new question for this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78410746/why-line-chart-doesnt-plot-measures-that-have-same-value-for-x-axis-in-power-bi

I responded to the new question. Don't forget to mark this as solved (the solution is that it is not currently possible). Thanks
